# How can one execute Powershell commands/ scripts on a remote Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Imagine I have two Virtual Machines in my Azure subscription.  From machine **Foo**, I’d like to be able to run Powershell commands and scripts on **Bar** under an admin account.

I will be using a Continuous Build Server on **Foo**, that when triggered it will create a (signed) script called **go.ps1** in a shared directory accessible by both **Foo** and **Bar**.  After that script is created, I want my CBS to have **Bar** copy that file to `C:\scripts\go.ps1` and execute it, as if I were an Admin sitting at **Bar**.  I’ve done something similar in the past on physical machines using psexec.  I assume there is something similar for Azure VMs.

Comment: You can also use  `invoke-command` to execute remote script or .ps1 file.

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual machines are on the same VNet using Azure provided DNS then psexec should work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can do something similar in the past on physical machines using [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). About Azure VMs, you could ensure the network connection is working between the two VMs. If they are in the different VNets, you could [peer the VNets with each other.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal) If they are in the same VNet, there are by default NSG inbound rule to allow any port from virtual network to another virtual network, so you just need to open the PSEXEC port 445 in the firewall inside the VM such as Windows Firewall.

This works for me. Enable the port 445 in the inbound rule of windows firewall with the private profile. I can run PsExec on the VM 10.0.0.4 to open the CMD in the VM 10.0.1.6.
[image]

[image]

Alternatively, there are many methods for you to [run scripts on the Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-scripts-in-vm). Feel free to let me know if you are anything unclear in the reply.